# How to make labels be center justified in an OpenLayers Web Map?

Tags: openlayers, labeling, qgis2web

I am trying to set the justification for some labels to be centered on the point.  I am using Qgis2web to create a web map.  Below is the relevant output code:

```
    var size = 0;
    var placement = 'point';
    
    var style_Equipment_0 = function(feature, resolution){
        var context = {
            feature: feature,
            variables: {}
        };
        var value = ""
        var labelText = "";
        size = 0;
        var labelFont = "26.0px \'MS Shell Dlg 2\', sans-serif";
        var labelFill = "#050000";
        var bufferColor = "";
        var bufferWidth = 0;
        var textAlign = "left";
        var offsetX = 8;
        var offsetY = 33;
        var placement = 'point';
        if (feature.get("LABEL") !== null) {
            labelText = String(feature.get("LABEL"));
        }
        var style = [ new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.RegularShape({radius: 8.0 + size, points: 6,
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'rgba(35,35,35,1.0)', lineDash: null, lineCap: 'butt', lineJoin: 'miter', width: 0}), fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(164,17,244,1.0)'})}),
            text: createTextStyle(feature, resolution, labelText, labelFont,
                                  labelFill, "center", bufferColor,
                                  bufferWidth)
        })];
    
        return style;
    };


var createTextStyle = function(feature, resolution, labelText, labelFont,
                               labelFill, placement, bufferColor,
                               bufferWidth) {

    if (feature.hide || !labelText) {
        return; 
    } 

    if (bufferWidth == 0) {
        var bufferStyle = null;
    } else {
        var bufferStyle = new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: bufferColor,
            width: bufferWidth
        })
    }
    
    var textStyle = new ol.style.Text({
        font: labelFont,
        text: labelText,
        textBaseline: "middle",
        textAlign: "left",
        offsetX: 8,
        offsetY: 3,
        placement: placement,
        maxAngle: 0,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: labelFill
        }),
        stroke: bufferStyle
    });

    return textStyle;
};
```

I tried modifying the placement variable and textAlign variable but nothing changes the justification of the labels.

[image: pictureofwebmap]

Comment: Please add the code for `createTextStyle` function. It's also not clear how do you want to center text: over the point, above/below point?

Comment: I updated my post with the requested info.

Comment: Since question is closed, you'll have to wait for three more reviewers requesting reopen (besides existing two), and then the answer will be possible.

Comment: I don't understand.  I added the requested info.

Comment: Question was most likely closed by 5 reviewers before you added requested info, Now it has to be reopened by 5 reviewers to be legitimate for answers. At the moment it has 3 reopen requests, so 2 more are needed.

Comment: @TomazicM I have the answer.  I didn't know to look for the createTextStyle function until you mentioned it in your first comment.  The createTextStyle function has default values for text justification so I just changed to what I need and it worked.

Comment: Positions for labels in qgis2web are difficult. This is an interactive map. Use other functions. 1. The user should see all informations at one point, if he click on the point. So you have many possibilities. 2. For a visually choice you could split your point layer (B, DE, AD, G...) - so you have different symbols or symbol colors and you have a better legend. I think this is better for a user. Too many labels are confusing.

Comment: Excuse me....not split your layer. Better: Categorized this layer.....