Position the labels centrally in qgis2opengis / qgis2web (OpenLayers)
In my case: qgis2opengis export
(problem also with OpenLayers export from qgis2web)
As it is not possible to make settings for label positioning via QGIS, editing must be carried out in openlayers export files.
There is already a question about this here in the forum, but unfortunately without an answer. (How to make labels be center justified in an OpenLayers Web Map?)
It is mentioned in a comment that the code can be customized within "createTextStyle".
The following screenshot shows this:

Appearance in QGIS, centered label
Result in qgis2opengis


What needs to be adjusted there to display labels centered?
In my example, I want to display the labels centered within polygons. The following JavaScript file is generated for the layer:
var size = 0;
var placement = 'point';

var style_polygonlayer1 = function(feature, resolution){
    var context = {
        feature: feature,
        variables: {}
    };
    var value = ""
    var labelText = "";
    size = 0;
    var labelFont = "15.600000000000001px \'Open Sans\', sans-serif";
    var labelFill = "#323232";
    var bufferColor = "";
    var bufferWidth = 0;
    var textAlign = "left";
    var offsetX = 8;
    var offsetY = 3;
    var placement = 'point';
    if (feature.get("labeltext") !== null) {
        labelText = String(feature.get("labeltext"));
    }
    var style = [ new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'rgba(35,35,35,1.0)', lineDash: null, lineCap: 'butt', lineJoin: 'miter', width: 0.988}),fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1.0)'}),
        text: createTextStyle(feature, resolution, labelText, labelFont,
                              labelFill, placement, bufferColor,
                              bufferWidth)
    })];

    var interval = 250;
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    if (geometry.getType() === 'MultiLineString') {
      geometry.getLineStrings().forEach(function (line) {
        var length = line.getLength();
        var intervals = Math.ceil(length / (interval * resolution));
        for (let i = 1; i < intervals; ++i) { //will not place labels at the start and end of the line
     // for (let i = 0; i <= intervals; ++i) to include them    
          var point = line.getCoordinateAt(i / intervals);
          var styletext = new ol.style.Style({
            text: new ol.style.Text({
              text: labelText,
              font: labelFont,
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: labelFill
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: bufferColor, 
                width: bufferWidth
              }),
            })
         });
          styletext.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(point));
          style.push(styletext);
        }
      });
    }

    return style;
};

If more information is required, I will also try to provide this.

Your code includes var textAlign = "left"; but you do not show where textAlign is used.   If it is used var textAlign = "center"; would be the setting you need.  Also adjust offsetY as necessary

No changes with these adjustments.

I suspect values are hardcoded in the definition of the createTextStyle function.  If so you will need to update that function to take and use more parameters.

Edit your code by changing these variables:
    var textAlign = "center";
    var offsetX = 0;
    var offsetY = -15;

and this:
     text: createTextStyle(feature, resolution, labelText, labelFont,
                                  labelFill, placement, bufferColor,
                                  bufferWidth, offsetX, offsetY, textAlign )

then edit functions.js file (resources folder) in this way:
var createTextStyle = function(feature, resolution, labelText, labelFont,
                               labelFill, placement, bufferColor,
                               bufferWidth, offsetX, offsetY, textAlign) {

    if (feature.hide || !labelText) {
        return; 
    } 

    if (bufferWidth == 0) {
        var bufferStyle = null;
    } else {
        var bufferStyle = new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: bufferColor,
            width: bufferWidth
        })
    }
    
    var textStyle = new ol.style.Text({
        font: labelFont,
        text: labelText,
        textBaseline: "middle",
        textAlign: textAlign,
        offsetX: offsetX,
        offsetY: offsetY,
        placement: placement,
        maxAngle: 0,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: labelFill
        }),
        stroke: bufferStyle
    });

    return textStyle;
};

Thanks for reporting, I will bring the change in future updates of qgis2web and qgis2opengis.

These also need to be passed to createTextStyle and the function updated to use them, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374510/how-to-make-labels-be-center-justified-in-an-openlayers-web-map for the code

Yes, thanks, you're right, I updated the answer.

Is the change already integrated in qgis2opengis version 2.21?

Similar problem with the numbers of clusters.

No, I have not yet brought the change to the new release, also because it would be useless if not integrated with the "Center Text" option of QGIS.
